# Different approval for different user accounts

Tags: users

I would like user account *A* to require approval before granting access, and user account *B* not to require any approval.

How can this be achieved?

Comment: Hello, and welcome on Drupal Answers. What is the difference between the first account, and the second account? Is there anything that makes the difference between those accounts?

Comment: Do you mean that if user *A* grants access to user *D*, then user *C* needs to approve this granting of access, but if user *B* grants access to user *D* then user *C* doesn't need to be involved?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used any module that can provide this kind of control.  What you can do is for the  second option create your own form and from backend create the user on form submit after proper validation.

Comment: I'm allowing two types of accounts to be registered. The first account (Default) requires admin approval before being accepted. The second account I want to be approved right away, no admin approval required.

Comment: Yes, Then for second account your your own form for registration and from backend use user_save() to save the user and approved that user id from query or using any function.

Answer (score 0):

You could have all users create accounts without the need for approval, and have user account A apply for the extra access needed using a contrib module.  See my previous answer about [organic groups and apply for role modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/49375/role-based-registration/49399#49399).